$L^\infty$ is a banach space
I have to show that $L^\infty$ is a banach space
My professor do this in this way
$1$ let $f_n$ be cauchy on $L^\infty$ i.e.  $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N : || f_n-f_m||_\infty<\epsilon \forall n,m>N $
so a.e. x $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<||f_n-f_m||\infty<\epsilon$
so $f_n$ is Cauchy a.e. x so it converges  so $\exists \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$
My professor after this do 2 things in bald that I don't understand why and at the end of the post there is my opinion

using $f_n$ is cauchy I have $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$
so for $m\rightarrow \infty |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ $\forall n>N $ a.e. x
and if $\epsilon =1$ I have $|f_{n_1}(x)-f(x)|<1$ so $||f||_\infty< 1+||f_{n_1}||_\infty$  so $ f \in  L^\infty$

we know by above $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \forall n>N $ so $||f_n-f||_\infty<\epsilon $ so $f_n\rightarrow f \in  L^\infty$


Things I  don't understand

why in the part 2 I have to use that f_n is Cauchy  to show
$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ $\forall n>N$ ?
Doesn't follow from the fact at point 1   $\exists \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$?

for point 2 and 3 I would have directly used $\exists \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ in order to say $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ $\forall n>N $ so $||f_n-f||\infty<\epsilon $ and this also prove $f \in L^\infty $ without using $\epsilon =1$ and $f_{n_1}$



Same answer for both . You want $N$ to be independent of $x$.
